# What program can help a REPL shell remember and search history?

Tags: command-line, emacs, lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I'm playing with Paul Graham's [arc](http://arclanguage.org/), and it's getting really annoying that the up arrow inserts ^[[A instead of the previous command, and ^R doesn't work as in shell. I vaguely remember there being a simple way to run Arc's REPL in a program which will remember the input history - does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/)?

Answer (score 7):

I like [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/) too, but other options include:

- [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) modes:

  - [shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html#Interactive-Shell)
  - [term](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html#Terminal-emulator)
  - [comint](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode)
  - [Slime](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) (works with Common Lisps and Clojure, probably not with Arc)
- ssfe (the frontend part of [sirc](http://www.iagora.com/~espel/sirc/sirc.html))
- [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) (especially if the REPL is written in Java, which arc is not)

Comment: I haven't thought about ssfe in over a decade, but it *would* work here. Nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

[nex3's arc on github](http://github.com/nex3/arc) comes with a script arc.sh which calls rlwrap by default, and an emacs mode to use the history with alt+P and alt+N.